# Android: Using ImageLoader in my Project?

Tags: java, android, image, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

So I'm a bit confused on how to properly implement an ImageLoader in my projects since most of the projects I refereed to dealt with creating a globally accessible ImageLoader object and accessing it through the Adapter. However my class is fixed like this:

```
public class ProductGridInflator extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{
    private int[] Imageid; 
    ArrayList<Product> dbProducts; 
    Context ctx; 
    int resource; 
    ArrayList<Image> urlArr = new ArrayList<Image>();
    ArrayList<Image> dbImages = new ArrayList<Image>();

    public ProductGridInflator(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Product> objects, ArrayList<Image> obj) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.dbProducts = objects;
        this.ctx = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.dbImages = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(dbProducts.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return dbProducts.size();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View child = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater(); // inflating your xml layout

        if (child == null) {            
            child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.productName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.grid_text); // fname is the reference to a textview

            holder.image = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            child.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (RecordHolder) child.getTag();
        }

        final Product user = dbProducts.get(position); 

        holder.productName.setText(user.getNAME());    

        for(int i=0;i<dbImages.size();i++)
        {
            if(dbImages.get(i).PID.equals(user.PID))
            {
                //holder.image is my image holder
                //This is where the URL should be accessed and image to be added
                String URL = dbImages.get(i).URL;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

        return child;
    }
```

So how do I implement a ImageLoader in this code and access the URL I specified guys? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Picasso library: https://github.com/square/picasso

It takes care of everything you need. It loads the image into your ImageView and even supports caching. It's very easy to use.

Comment: I'm using Picaso now but it doesn't load certain pics! I have no idea why.. the size was similar to the others and the type and resolutions were similar but still it doesn't load the images most of the time

Comment: Did you check that the image urls are valid? Otherwise I have no clue. Up to now Picasso always loaded all my images successfully.